# Flutter SharedPreferences resetting the data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code in flutter using `SharedPreferences` to store data:

```
Future<bool> setUserStatus(String userStatus) async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('userStatus', 'active');
  return true;
}
```

Is it possible to use this same setUserStatus in another file, which will get this main.dart imported to it, and change the `SharedPreferences` data to something else based on the actions taken in the other file

Comment: With what you are saying, yes that's possible. You can import this file and use this method anywhere in the project. Every time you call this function it will alter data in 'userStatus' in ```SharedPreferences```

Comment: @JagrajSingh so when I call the method do I also have to include the beginning part (Future<bool>)? And also do I also have to add a prefs.clear before resetting or straight up set the new value? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: yes you need to add Future<bool> and await, thats the best practice. And it is not necessary to prefs.clear you can directly reset it and prefs.clear will delete all saved shared preferences, If you want to remove particular key value from shared preferences with key name you can do it like this way as follows.

SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.remove('KeyNameHere');

Comment: @dhanasekar okay. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this,

`await setUserStatus( status );`
if you don't want to wait for the future to complete just remove `await` from the begining.

Calling `prefs.clear()`will erase all the preferences set on the device. so I would suggest not to use that here. If you want to clear a particular preference just use
`prefs.remove(key)` or `prefs.setString(key,null)`